# UnicodeString to char* (UTF-8)

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8, internationalization, icu

I am using the ICU library in C++ on OS X. All of my strings are UnicodeStrings, but I need to use system calls like fopen, fread and so forth. These functions take const char* or char* as arguments. I have read that OS X supports UTF-8 internally, so that all I need to do is convert my UnicodeString to UTF-8, but I don't know how to do that.

UnicodeString has a toUTF8() member function, but it returns a ByteSink. I've also found these examples: http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk/source/samples/ucnv/convsamp.cpp and read about using a converter, but I'm still confused. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

call `UnicodeString::extract(...)` to extract into a char*, pass NULL for the converter to get the default converter (which is in the charset which your OS will be using).

Comment: Thank you! That does work. I'm not sure about the destCapacity argument and the length of the UnicodeString. This code works: http://codepad.org/blaSP0ex but you'll notice I double the .length() of the UnicodeString manually to make up for the multibyte string. How can I make sure there is enough space in my char* dest?

Comment: http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classUnicodeString.html#125255f27efd817e38806d76d9567345

It will return the length needed for the output string and a U_BUFFER_OVERFLOW_ERROR in status if there wasn't enough space. See http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings#TOC-Using-C-Strings:-NUL-Terminated-vs%2e

Comment: Thank you. The documentation says that it's best to guess the size and if there's a buffer overflow error, then to call the extract function again with the length returned from the first call. I do that here: http://codepad.org/nyp5yJWB but the second call still fails, even though I provide it with the correct length returned from the first extract call. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I forgot delete[] instead of delete, and I don't think I need sizeof (I use C usually), but those are minor details.

Comment: That's right, but you need to reset the error code after the failure. ICU functions just exit if the error is already set.  http://userguide.icu-project.org/design#TOC-Error-Handling

Comment: Thank you! Everything works now. I don't mean to keep pestering you, but it just seems like you're the only one who knows anything about ICU.

Comment: You might want to amend this answer; while correct at the time of writing, since ICU 4.2 we have more comfortable solutions (as pointed out by the other two answers). FWIW, I found this answer while looking for a *legacy* solution, so have an upvote. ;-)

Comment: extract didn't work for me. Always some error. I need to log a value in a file, i used charAt(index): log_statement_orig.charAt(0)<< "\n"; log_statement_orig.charAt(1)<< "\n"; ... seems stupid but it helped. I wrote the output integers in a unicode converter (from decimal to unicode) and I had the value of the string. Only the build of my project lasts 30 minutes and after few errors i decided to follow this way. Of course it was only for a debug, not usable in production code.

Answer (score 4):

[ICU User Guide > UTF-8](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/utf-8) provides methods and descriptions of doing that.

> The simplest way to use UTF-8 strings in UTF-16 APIs is via the C++ `icu::UnicodeString` methods `fromUTF8(const StringPiece &utf8)` and `toUTF8String(StringClass &result)`. There is also `toUTF8(ByteSink &sink)`.

And `extract()` is not prefered now.

> Note: `icu::UnicodeString` has constructors, `setTo()` and `extract()` methods which take either a converter object or a charset name. These can be used for UTF-8, but are not as efficient or convenient as the `fromUTF8()`/`toUTF8()`/`toUTF8String()` methods mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
std::string utf8;
uStr.toUTF8String(utf8);
```

Comment: This is an old post, as you can see. Since then I am working on `go` and `java`.

`std::string` should be taken care, but I do not remember what `icu` ownership was for `uStr`

Comment: @Johnny_D, `std::string` always contains custom array of char. So, don't worry about `std::string utf8;`, it will destruct custom copy of string array.